# How to change a Google Map PolygonOption fill color after its drawn

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

Is there a way to change a PolygonOption's fill color after it has been drawn and update a  Google map without clearing and redrawing it?

What  I'm currently doing is

```
    polygonOptions.fillColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.polygonSolidFill));
    polygonOptions.strokeWidth(2);
    polygonOptions.strokeColor(Color.BLACK);
    // Add some LatLngs 
    googleMap.addPolygon(polygonOptions);
```

When the user is at a certain location I want to change the fill color. What I'm doing to achieve the color update is

```
    polygonOptions.fillColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.polygonSolidFill2));
    googleMap.clear();
    googleMap.addPolygon(polygonOptions);
```

However there is a small flicker in the map when its cleared and redrawn which I would like to avoid.

Comment: so what you are asking is if there is a way to refresh the polygon without refreshing the entire map?

Comment: I believe so @toidiu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think just call like this:

```
Polygon polygon = googleMap.addPolygon(polygonOptions);
polygon.setFillColor(Color.RED);
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polygon.html#setFillColor(int)

Comment: YOu are adding a new polygon, what happens to the original one?